# Split a video file into separate video and audio files using a single ffmpeg call?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Background: I would like to use MLT `melt` to render a project, but I'd like that render to result with separate audio and video files. I'd intend to use `melt`'s "consumer" `avformat` which uses `ffmpeg`'s libraries, so I'm formulating this question as for `ffmpeg`.

According to [Useful FFmpeg Commands For Converting Audio & Video Files (labnol.org)](http://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/), the following is possible:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -t 00:00:50 -c copy small-1.mp4 -ss 00:00:50 -codec copy small-2.mp4
```

... which slices the "merged" audio+video files into two separate "chunk" files, which are also audio+video files, in a single call; that's not what I need.

Then, [ffmpeg Documentation (ffmpeg.org)](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), mentions this:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -map_channel 0.0.0 OUTPUT_CH0 -map_channel 0.0.1 OUTPUT_CH1
```

... which splits the entire duration of the content of two channels of a stereo *audio* file, into two mono files; that's more like what I need, except I want to split an A+V file into a stereo audio file, and a video file.

So I tried this with [elephantsdream_teaser.ogv](http://archive.org/download/Elephants_Dream_teaser_2/elephantsdream_teaser.ogv):

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/elephantsdream_teaser.ogv \
  -map 0.0 -vcodec copy ele.ogv -map 0.1 -acodec copy ele.ogg
```

... but this fails with "*Number of stream maps must match number of output streams*" (even if zero-size `ele.ogv` and `ele.ogg` are created).

So my question is - is something like this possible with `ffmpeg`, and if it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Your command works, but you need to specify mapping with columns instead of dots as so:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/elephantsdream_teaser.ogv -map 0:0 -vcodec copy ele.ogv -map 0:1 -acodec copy ele.ogg
```

You might want to test with a more recent build of ffmpeg. Mine gave correct errors for your command:

```
[ogg @ 00000000043f8480] Invalid stream specifier: .0.
Last message repeated 3 times
Stream map '0.0' matches no streams.
```

Comment: Using `0:v` instead of `0:0`, and `0:a` instead of `0:1` is more efficient and less prone to incorrect mapping (unless the input has multiple streams per stream type, then `0:v:0` can be used to specify).